# Passing List between Views in SwiftUi

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-view

I'm making a ToDo list app on my own to try to get familiar with iOS development and there's this one problem I'm having:

I have a separate `View` linked to enter in a new task with a `TextField`. Here's the code for this file:

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddTask: View {
     @State public var task : String = ""
     @State var isUrgent: Bool = false // this is irrelevant to this problem you can ignore it

    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Add New Task")
                    .bold()
                    .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                TextField("New Task...", text: $task)
                Toggle("Urgent", isOn: $isUrgent)
                    .padding(.vertical)
                Button("Add task", action: {"call some function here to get what is 
in the text field and pass back the taskList array in the Content View"})
               
                 
                
            }.padding()
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
}


struct AddTask_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddTask()
    }
}
```

So what I need to take the task variable entered and insert it into the array to be displayed in the list in my main `ContentView` file.

Here's the `ContentView` file for reference:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var taskList = ["go to the bakery"]
    
    struct AddButton<Destination : View>: View {

        var destination:  Destination

        var body: some View {
            NavigationLink(destination: self.destination) { Image(systemName: "plus") }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationView {
                List {
                    ForEach(self.taskList, id: \.self) {
                    item in Text(item)
                    }
                }.navigationTitle("Tasks")
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: HStack { AddButton(destination: AddTask())})
            }
            
        }
        
}
struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
  }
}
```

I need a function to take the task entered in the `TextField`, and pass it back in the array in the `ContentView` to be displayed in the `List` for the user

-thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

You can add a closure property in your `AddTask` as a callback when the user taps `Add Task`. Just like this:

```swift
struct AddTask: View {
  var onAddTask: (String) -> Void // <-- HERE
  @State public var task: String = ""
  @State var isUrgent: Bool = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Add New Task")
          .bold()
          .font(.title)
        TextField("New Task...", text: $task)
        Toggle("Urgent", isOn: $isUrgent)
          .padding(.vertical)
        Button("Add task", action: {
          onAddTask(task)
        })
      }.padding()
      Spacer()
    }
  }

}
```

Then, in `ContentView`:

```swift
.navigationBarItems(
    trailing: HStack {
      AddButton(
        destination: AddTask { task in
            taskList.append(task)
        }
      )
  }
)
```

[@jnpdx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560942/jnpdx) provides a good solution by passing `Binding` of taskList to `AddTask`. But I think `AddTask` is used to add a new task so it should only focus on **The New Task** instead of full taskList.

Comment: This is a good solution and I agree with your point about the focus of the view. I would, however, probably not include a default value for `onAddTask`, since the view would be useless without it (although I understand it avoids the problem of having to pass an empty closure in the preview).

Comment: @jnpdx you are correct, the default value of `onAddTask` is no need.

Comment: @jctaoo this looks good, but I'm getting an error for not passing in a argument into the preview provider in the AddTask file: "Missing argument for parameter 'onAddTask' in call"